# Using scanf funciton in printf to get values

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main () 
{
    int i;
    printf ("%d", scanf ("%d", &i));

}
```

while using the

> scanf

function in

> printf

statement,when i give any integer as input it prints only 1.

> **Input:5 output:1**

i am beginner in c ,so kindly help.
can any one explain this program ?

Comment: You are printing the return value of `scanf`, not the value you scanned. Please read the documentation before posting a question.

Comment: documentation where can find it?

Comment: By googling "scanf"? Did you even try...

Comment: yes i searched before posting.

Comment: This was my first link when I searched for "scanf": https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm

Comment: If you are a beginner, this is the totally wrong point to start. It is never, ever going to be useful. Please start somewhere else, like reading a book.

Comment: i agree but i can find useful solutions here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf()` returns number of receiving arguments successfully assigned or EOF in case of failure.

Read more about scanf() [**here**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

In context of your program, when you give input `5` the `scanf()` successfully assign it to receiving argument `i` and since the receiving argument is `1`, `scanf()` is returning `1` which is getting printed. Hence you are getting output `1`.
Try to give a character as input and check the output.

Answer (score 0):

you need something like this

EDIT - [more info here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-s-scanf-s-l-wscanf-s-wscanf-s-l?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(STDIO%2Fscanf_s)%3Bk(scanf_s)%3Bk(DevLang-C%2B%2B)%3Bk(TargetOS-Windows)%26rd%3Dtrue)

scanf_s is for reading from console
printf to print on screen

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    scanf_s("%d", &i);
    printf("%d", i);
    return 0;
}
```